# How to pass all props dynamically to child component

Tags: vuejs2

How to pass all props dynamically to child component? As an example consider a case:

```
// wrapper around a component my-wrapper.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <third-party-component />
  </div>
</template>
```

third-party-component is a component which can accept number of attributes like value, disabled, clicked, etc. How I can use my-wrapper in way that whatever I passed as props to it it will be transferred to third-party-component like

```
<my-wrapper :value="myVal" :disabled="field.isDisabled" />
```

Answer (score 20):

By default the attributes you add on to `my-wrapper` will be bound to the root element which is `div`. To avoid this set [`inheritAttrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) option to `false`

Then you can bind all the attributes to using `v-bind="$attrs"` where [`$attrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs) contains parent-scope attribute bindings (except for `class` and `style`)

```
// wrapper around a component my-wrapper.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <third-party-component v-bind="$attrs"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        inheritAttrs: false
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It's really helpful when used in conjunction with a `<component>` element as the root of a custom element to allow the tag used for rendering to be changed with a prop.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, exactly were I was looking for. Small side note. If you are using Typescript based components, you can pass the same `inheritAttrs` option within the `@Component` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I would set identical props to the wappers and use them in the template ... 
But there is many ways, it easy to speak from parent to childs.

https://en.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props
https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands

---- MyWrapper.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <third-party-component :value="value" :disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
 @import third-party-component from '../..? ./components/thirdPartyComponent.vue'
 export default {
   name: 'MyWrapper',
   props: ['value', 'disabled'],
   components: {
     third-party-component // local component, you can use global
   } 
   //... data, computed ...
 }
</script>
```

----- MyAppli.vue

```
<template>
   <my-wrapper :value="myVal" :disabled="field.isDisabled" />
</template>
<script>
  import my-wrapper from '../..? ../components/MyWrapper.vue'
  export default {
   name: 'MyApp',
   components: {
     my-wrapper // local component, you can use global
   } ....
```